# jaxbUnmarshaller is not able to unmarchal a japanese characters

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml which is having japanese characters. The Xml is getting marshalled correctly but which jaxbUnmarshalling all the characters are getting converted into '?'
Please find the Code Below :-

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

JAXBExample

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class JAXBExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Customer customer = new Customer();
      customer.setId(100);
      customer.setName("株式会社三菱東京UFJ銀行");
      customer.setAge(29);

      try {

        File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING,"UTF-8");
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Conversion.java

```
public class Conversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(customer.getName());

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

OutPUT :-

XML :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer id="100">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>株式会社三菱東京UFJ銀行</name>
</customer>
```

After running the Conversion.java class i am getting the below output:-

Customer Name ????????UFJ??

Please help i have searched the net but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing a `Reader` yourself with the correct encoding and feed that `Reader` to `Unmarshaller#unmarshal()` instead of your `File`:

```
File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "utf-8")) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        System.out.println(customer.getName());

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, if your platform encoding is something like `latin1`, then `System.out` uses it and corrupts the data being output (replacing it with question marks). Please run your program like this:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 JAXBExample
```

By the way, this may be sufficient by itself, without the `Reader`-related twist, to solve the problem, as `unmarshal()` method should respect encoding specified in the XML file.

Comment: Pretty strange, I ran this code with the file supplied by you, and it worked. The output was `株式会社三菱東京UFJ銀行`. Do you mean it still produces the same garbage consisting of question marks? Could you please post the full source code you got after applying my suggestion?

Comment: Launching with `-Dfile.encoding=latin1` makes my program produce garbage as well. But this is probably because System.out uses `latin1` too, so it corrupts characters on output and not on input from XML. Let me update the answer.